# Is it possible to add the blur effect in video?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I'm working on video part in my Application. I would like to show my video with the blur effect in top and bottom. Is this possible in Swift?

Reference: Twitter has this functionality in their Application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can if twitter did it.

Just add on top of your Video Layer, a `Visual Effect View with Blur`. If you use Storyboards, you can just drag and drop this view, add constraints, and it will work.